# Explanation of JVM bytecode

Tags: jvm, bytecode

Can someone explain how the numbers alongside JVM Opcodes are calculated? 
I think it is like 1 byte for the opcode and rest of the bytes for operands. Am I correct?

Example:

```
Method int add12and13() 
 0 bipush 12 
 2 bipush 13 
 4 invokestatic #3 // Method Example.addTwoStatic(II)I 
 7 ireturn
```

Comment: Some instructions are just 1 byte.

Comment: If you are interested in such topics, you should start at [the official source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html) first.

Comment: Don’t forget to accept an answer if it satisfies your needs. Otherwise, add to your question what is still unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. This is bytecode offset from the method beginning.

`bipush` has 1 byte parameter, so it totally takes 2 bytes.

`invokestatic` takes 3 bytes: opcode + 2 bytes for a constant pool index, that is, offset of the next instruction will be +3 bytes from this `invokestatic`.